# Correlation statistics

Tags: excel, correlation

Naive Question:

[image: Correlation]

In the attached snapshot, I am trying to figure out the correlation concept when applied to actual values and to calculation performed on those actual values and creating a new stream of data.

In the example,

Columns A,B,C,D,E have very different correlation but when I do a rolling sum on the same columns to get G,H,I,J,K the correlation is very much the same(negative or positive.

Are these to different types of correlation or am I missing out on something.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, these are different correlations. It's similar to if you were to measure acceleration over time of 5 automobiles (your first piece of data) and correlate those accelerations. Each car accelerates at different rates over time leaving your correlation all over the place.

Your second set of data would be the velocity of each car at each point in time. Because each car is accelerating at a pretty constant rate (and doing so in two different directions from the starting point) you either get a big positive or  big negative correlation.

It's not necessary that you get that big positive or big negative correlation in the second set, but since your data in each list is consistently positive or negative and grows at a consistent rate, it correlates with either similar lists.

Comment: Thanks @JNevill for the explanation. 
Just another quick question: Which correlation would be a better understanding of the data then? 1st or the 2nd set. I know there is no best answer to this but just curious.

Comment: It depends on the data and your needs. I can't imagine that +/-1 is really all that helpful since it's really only telling you the direction of your rate of change of the first set of data. It might help if you plot both sets of data and visually see why the correlation is acting like is.